# Help with foreign_relay subscription

Tags: ros, multimaster, multiplemachines

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I'm having difficulties using foreign_relay. I find that I can use it in advertise mode, to push a topic from my local master to the remote master, ie:

```
rosrun foreign_relay foreign_relay adv http://other-machine:11311/ /from_other/test /test
```

However, I can't seem to get it working in subscribe mode, ie:

```
rosrun foreign_relay foreign_relay sub http://other-machine:11311/ /test /from_other/test
```

By adding some debug shouts, I can see that the foreign_subscribe() function completes successfully, but in_cb() never gets called and the /from_other/test topic is never created on my local master.

In all cases, I am able to set my ROS_MASTER_URI to the other machine and publish/subscribe with the foreign master using rostopic. So I believe that indicates that my network and environment setup is correct. I can even successfully get a remote subscription by doing this:

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://other-machine:11311
rosrun foreign_relay foreign_relay adv http://my-machine.local:11311 /other/test /test
```

This seems like a really awkward hack, though.

Has anyone else had luck getting bidirectional foreign relay working?

I'm using ROS Electric, with the current apt version of multimaster_experimental on a Lucid box, and the current source (r16648) on an Oneiric box. The apt packaged version does not work on my Oneiric machine due to a shared library mismatch issue.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31932/help-with-foreign_relay-subscription/) by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1153 on 2012-04-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on 2012-04-18**:
Oh wow, thanks. This seems much more complete and polished than multimaster_experimental. I've added a note to the foreign_relay page directing visitors on to multimaster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not exactly an answer, but I find the multimaster http://ros.org/wiki/multimaster easier to use in publishing/subscribing on another master. It's bidirectional and only the config file requires updating.

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2012-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0